# Strange behaviour between foreach and for loop

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

My windows phone 7 silverlight app before placing pushpins on a map layer removes any that are previously there.

I was doing this in a foreach loop as follows:

```
            //Clear previous pins
        try
        {
            foreach (UIElement p in PushPinLayer.Children)
            {
                if(p.GetType() == typeof(Pushpin))
                {
                    PushPinLayer.Children.Remove(p);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            //TODO: For some reason the foreach loop above causes an invalid Operation exception.
            //Cathing the error here until I can work out why it is happening.
        }
```

This code removes any pushpins as required but after the last loop would throw an exception "Invalid Operation" I re-wrote it as a for loop:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < PushPinLayer.Children.Count; i++)
        {
            if (PushPinLayer.Children[i].GetType() == typeof(Pushpin))
            {
                PushPinLayer.Children.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
```

Which works fine, however I can't see why the foreach is throwing an error.

Comment: I doubt the for loop works like you want... I think it's always skipping the item right after the one you remove. You should walk the list backwards rather than forward.

Comment: Personally, whilst I am aware of the behavioural differences, workarounds and quasi-reasoning (wrt foreach/enumerators), I'd really like to see this question answered in terms of fundamental principals as it's been bugging me not having that explanation and I haven't had the time to dig into the language/framework mechanics in this detail or look to see if it's been answered better already. At it's root, what makes this approach fall down? Jon, this one has your name written all over it ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is very normal,

**You cannot remove items from a list which you still use in the foreach list.** 
*better then removing the item would be to create a new list, and every time it is not a pushpin type, add the object to the new list.*

This way the original list is not altered and you won't get an exception.

I find it strange that the for loop works, but if it does, it would mean that the way they are itterated is different. The for loop will be copied to another memory location and used for the for loop so that the original one, in which you remove items, is not used anymore by the for loop. The foreach loop will get parameters from the list, the you remove items, so the list and the parameters become concurrent.

Comment: It's not strange that the for loop works. As far as the collection is concerned, there's just a bunch of calls to .RemoveAt(n). Whereas the foreach loop is a full state machine tightly connected to the collection that expects the collection to stay the same during its lifetime.

Comment: Yes, but I would expect the same for the for loop. The for loop will go out of bound tough, because the size is only read once, and the becomes smaller

Comment: Hmm, why do you say the size is only evaluated once? Surely the entire for-condition will be evaluated at each iteration? (the spec doesn't say anything more than "it is evaluated")

Comment: because of 2 reasons, performance, and I had the problem once before, that the count of the list stayed the same after removing items in a for loop. But as you mention it, I am not sure anymore, so I can't say with certainty, I should check it :D

Comment: This code never terminates (both release and debug build), indicating that it is in fact evaluated fully each iteration: `var lst = new List<int>(); for (int i = -1; i < lst.Count; i++) {    lst.Add(i); }`

Answer (score 3):

Your `foreach` loop uses and `Enumerator` to iterate the objects in your collection. When you delete an object from the collection the `Enumerator` is no longer valid as it references object that no longer exist. This causes a `InvalidOperationException`

The best way to remove them is using a `for` loop and even better doing it in reverse.

```
    for (int i = PushPinLayer.Children.Count - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
    {
        if (PushPinLayer.Children[i].GetType() == typeof(Pushpin))
        {
            PushPinLayer.Children.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
```

This will ensure that as the items are removed your `Index` `i` does not exceed the number of items in your collection.

Comment: FWIW, it doesn't matter if doing it in reverse or not, the for-condition seems to be evaluated fully each iteration so it will pick up any changes in size of the list.

Answer (score 2):

When you change the content of the collection, the enumerator used in the foreach loop becomes invalid. You can't change a collection while you enumerate it.

Here's a workaround:

```
        List<UIElement> toRemove = new List<UIElement>();
        foreach (UIElement p in PushPinLayer.Children)
        {
            if(p.GetType() == typeof(Pushpin))
            {
                toRemove.Add(p);
            }
        }
        foreach(UIElement p in toRemove)
        {
            PushPinLayer.Children.Remove(p);
        }
```

Alternatively, you could use the RemoveAll method, which takes a predicate as a parameter:

```
        PushPinLayer.Children.RemoveAll(p => p is Pushpin);
```

Answer (score 2):

Others have already given you the reason for the problem so I just thought I'd post a LINQ version of a work around

```
var toRemove = PushPinLayer.Children.OfType<Pushpin>().ToList();
// since toRemove is a separate collection, it's safe to do this now:
foreach (var child in toRemove)
   PushPinLayer.Children.Remove(child)
```

Comment: RemoveAll takes a predicate, not a list

Answer (score 2):

Since others have already answered your question, I will only comment on your usage of `xxx.GetType() == typeof(Pushpin)`. You could check whether something is a pushpin by simply using the C# reserved keyword **is**. e.g.:

```
if (p is Pushpin) {...}
```

Comment: Thank you that is much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You must not change the collection while foreaching through it.